# Ruby on Rails: set specific serializer for polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to override the default serializer for a polymorphic relationship. I have:

```
class NotificationListSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
end
```

If `notifiable` is an Organization, the organization is serialized with OrganizationSerializer. If `notifiable` is a Group, the group is serialized with GroupSerializer. This makes perfect sense, but how can I specify a different serializer, depending on the class?

For example, if `notifiable` is an Organization, I would like to use SparseOrganizationSerializer instead of OrganizationSerializer. How can I achieve this?

I'm pretty sure this is documented, but I'm having a hard time following and finding any examples.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/serializers.md):

> ## Polymorphic Relationships
>
> Polymorphic relationships are serialized by specifying the relationship, like any other association. For example:
>
> ```
> class PictureSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
>   has_one :imageable
> end
> ```
>
> You can specify the serializers by overriding serializer_for. For more context about polymorphic relationships, see the tests for each adapter.
>
> ## Overriding association serializer lookup
>
> If you want to define a specific serializer lookup for your associations, you can override the ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for method to return a serializer class based on defined conditions.
>
> ```
> class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
>   def self.serializer_for(model, options)
>     return SparseAdminSerializer if model.class == 'Admin'
>     super
>   end
>   # the rest of the serializer
> end
> ```

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this. Also, any idea to prevent n+1 loads for these polymorphic serializers?

Comment: If anyone else is having trouble with this, I actually needed model.class.to_s instead of just model.class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use belongs_to :notifiable with &block option to specify fit serializer there.

Comment: Can you give an example? What if someone wanted to specify various different serializers based on various polymorphic associations to avoid multiple attributes that might be relevant or not, depending on the association?